# what jar to use in pom.xml for weblogic wrapper?

Tags: oracle, weblogic

In java class I am trying to get rid of ClassCast exception as below.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Array_oracle_sql_ARRAY
```

Using

```
if (someArray instanceof weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Array) 
ar = (oracle.sql.ARRAY)     ((weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Array)someArray).unwrap(Class.forName("oracle.sql.ARRAY"))); 
else 
ar = (oracle.sql.ARRAY)someArray;
```

But I am not able to find the maven dependency having weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Array

http://adfpractice-fedor.blogspot.com/2011/09/weblogic-wrapping-data-types.html

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the tutorial that you're reffering to was created using JDeveloper, which has a bunch of WebLogic jars bundled.

If you're not using JDeveloper, here's what you can do - first identify which jar contains the class (the most lightweight one I could find is com.bea.core.datasource6.jar - this jar is a part of JDeveloper):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.bea.core.datasource6</artifactId>
    <version>12.2.1-0-0</version> 
</dependency>
```

then, in order to resolve the jar, either:

- use [the Oracle Maven repository](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/MAVEN/config_maven_repo.htm#MAVEN9010) (you need to register in order to use it):

OR

- use [the Oracle Maven Synchronization plugin](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/MAVEN/config_maven.htm#MAVEN311) (WebLogic or JDeveloper install required) to populate your local (or remote) Maven repository with Oracle jars - this basically takes most jars from a WebLogic install and runs a `mvn install:install-file` on them